When does a linearly ordered group inherit a commutative ring structure from its group of automorphisms?
I have been seeking an alternative characterisation of the real numbers recently, to see more clearly what analysis might look like in other possible number systems (rationals, hyperreals, dyadic rationals, etc.). In this investigation, I found that the natural notion of a continuous parameter is captured by a densely ordered abelian group, and that the maximal Archimedean such group is the additive group of real numbers.
An interesting feature of this result is that the real numbers has a multiplicative structure, but nothing in our construction even hints at it. One is led to ask: does this multiplicative structure have an ordered-group interpretation? I was unsure until quite recently, when I realised that we could conceptualise it in terms of endomorphisms. Specifically, given a densely ordered abelian group $A$, consider the group $\mathrm{Aut}(A, \leq)$ consisting of automorphisms of $A$ which either preserve or reverse the ordering; then, if $A = (\mathbb R, +)$, this group acts freely and transitively on $A^*$. If we choose an element $1 \in A^*$, therefore, we can identify each $a \in A^*$ with the unique $\varphi_a \in \mathrm{Aut}(A, \leq)$ for which $\varphi_a(1) = a$.
Thus, $A^*$ naturally inherits a ring structure, with multiplication given by composition of the corresponding automorphisms. Indeed, one has that $(\varphi_a \circ \varphi_b)(1) = \varphi_a(b) = ab$ for $a, b \in \mathbb R^*$.
However, this realisation raises two questions:

Firstly, can we always faithfully transfer the multiplicative structure on $\mathrm{Aut}(A, \leq)$ over to $A$; that is, when can we say that $\mathrm{Aut}(A, \leq)$ acts freely and transitively? I believe I am able to show that $\mathrm{Aut}(A, \leq)$ acts freely if and only if $A$ is Archimedean, but I am unsure of any conditions for transitivity.
Secondly, when is $\mathrm{Aut}(A, \leq)$ commutative? It seems a strange coincidence that multiplication happens to be commutative for $\mathbb R$, so what conditions on $A$ might force this to be the case? (This could also provide a deeper insight into why multiplication of real numbers is commutative.)

Any input is appreciated!
EDIT: Minutes after writing this, I found this relevant MO question! Its answer demonstrates that a classification of torsion-free groups with commutative endomorphism rings is unlikely. However, I still think my question is distinct and interesting because we are restricting to linearly ordered groups, which is already a huge restriction, and we also only allow automorphisms respecting the order structure.
